# Make: make all that fit rule

Tags: makefile

I’m trying to learn makefiles.
I have the following Makefile:

```
ctx/%.ctx: rst/%.rst
    texlua rst_parser.lua $< $@

pdf: ctx
    mkdir -p pdf
    cd pdf; context ../ctx/main.ctx

ctx: rst
    mkdir -p ctx

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f pdf/*.log pdf/*.aux pdf/*.pgf pdf/*.top pdf/*.tuc
```

As you can see, all three prerequisites are directories; `rst`, `ctx` and `pdf`. The prerequisites recurse down to “rst”. I’ll edit files in `ctx` manually and files in `rst`, which get converted into files in `ctx`.

What should I do to make `make` make `pdf` :) the following way:

1. Look if something in `ctx` and/or something in `rst` has changed.
2. If only something in `ctx` was changed, make `pdf`, else make `ctx`.
3. If something in `rst` has changed, use the first rule to make the corresponding file in `ctx`, then make `ctx` and then make `pdf`.

My problem is now that I don’t know how to tell `make` “In order to make `ctx` when files in `rst` are changed, use the first rule (`ctx/%.ctx: ctx/%.rst`) to make each matching file in `ctx` from the corresponding one in `rst`”

Comment: and why does a plain `make` read my mind and behaves like `make pdf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear (e.g. you're confusing the directory `pdf/` with the makefile target `pdf`), but this should do what I think you want:

```
TARGETS := $(wildcard rst/*.rst)
TARGETS := $(patsubst rst/%.rst,%,$(TARGETS))

ctx/%.ctx: rst/%.rst    # I assume you didn't mean ctx/%.rst
  texlua rst_parser.lua $< $@

pdf: ctx
  mkdir -p pdf
  cd pdf; context ../ctx/main.ctx

.PHONY:cxt
ctx: $(patsubst %,ctx/%.ctx, $(TARGETS))
  mkdir -p ctx
```

And the reason a plain `make` builds `pdf` is that when you invoke Make without a target it chooses the default target, which is the first target (unless you do some tinkering), which in this case is `pdf`. (The pattern rule doesn't count.)

**EDIT:**
Now that I think of it, what I posted above is kind of clunky, and it will always run the `pdf` rule, even if nothing has changed. This is somewhat better:

```
# You're right, this is better.        
CTX_TARGETS := $(patsubst rst/%.rst,ctx/%.ctx, $(wildcard rst/*.rst))

pdf: $(CTX_TARGETS)
  mkdir -p pdf
  cd pdf; context ../ctx/main.ctx

$(CTX_TARGETS): ctx/%.ctx: rst/%.rst ctx
  texlua rst_parser.lua $< $@    

ctx:
  mkdir -p ctx
```

I made `ctx` PHONY because I was wrestling with the case when the *directory* exists, but the *rule* should still be run. It turned out to be unnecessary (as you might guess from the fact that I didn't catch the typo).

And yes, prerequisites are the names of files or dirs (or `PHONY` targets). My point was that phrases like "make `pdf`" are a little confusing if pdf is both a directory and a rule which builds it (and does other things).

The problem with using directories as targets is that they don't obey intuitive rules of modification time: if you modify a file in a directory, the directory's mod time doesn't change. It's also tricky to change the mod time deliberately, since `touch` doesn't do it (don't ask me why it's legal to `touch` a directory if it does nothing). It can be done, e.g. by adding and deleting a dummy file, but it's ugly.

Comment: thanks, i’ll ry to understand what you did and then accept your answer. @targets/dirs: but prerequisites do represent files/dir of the same name?

Comment: Now I get it, thanks! Only one thing: Why is ctx (typo here) `.PHONY`?

Comment: Oh, and is there a reason, why you don’t do `$(patsubst rst/%.rst,ctx/%.ctx,$(TARGETS))`?